# Tor 0.2.7.6 uses 100% of CPU all the time!

Tags: configuration, linux, performance

I just updated my Tor with [`tor-0.2.7.6.tar.gz`](https://dist.torproject.org/?C=M;O=D), but when I run `tor`, it uses 100% of one of my CPU's cores, even if I run something simple like `tor --version`. What is going on?

Comment: What kind of GNU/Linux (distribution) are you running? Did you compile it for yourself? If yes, please tell some details of how you compiled it.

Comment: @JensKubieziel I use Slackware and used the [Tor SlackBuild](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/network/tor/) to build it.

Comment: Try to remove --enable-openbsd-malloc option

Comment: please post your build options in the question + `uname -a`

Comment: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18028#comment:1 > When it's using all the cpu, could somebody try using oprofile or prof or gdb or anything to figure out where it's going? > What's the last version that _didn't_ have this problem for you?